# Maximum current in MIL-spec D38999 circular connectors

Tags: current, connector, datasheet, heat, ampacity

1. Talking about d38999, does a current/contact heat diagram exist?
2. What a normal d38999 contact temperature can reach before getting damaged?
   Datasheet of various vendor display a nominal ampacity that I suppose is referring to a steady state current but I am not sure about it.

Comment: Power-BreechTM connectors are rated up to 900 amps. These shell size 33 – 57 solutions utilize MIL--DTL--38999 Series IV derived coupling mechanisms.  Ask supplier for max temp rise of the gold plated contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Amphenol rate max current with ambient temperature which combined reaches the same contact temperature for excessive corrosive stress and reduced MTBF.

E.g. https://www.amphenol-aerospace.com/resources/literature/view/38999-connectors-with-power-contacts

However you must request validation test reports to ensure this also includes aging and contact stress from such contaminants as space dust and gamma radiation.  Arhennius law dictates acceleating failure rates with temp rise and loss of rated margin with the application to compute FIT rates.  I would expect field experience of such failure rates must exists from Mil-Std 883 data.